# Sinatra namespace not working

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app where I want to use namespace to make it more clean. I've installed the `sinatra-contrib` gem and added `require 'sinatra/namespace'`. When I run the app with `puma config.ru` I keep getting the following error:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/1.8.7/fixnum/div.rb:1: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/1.8.7/fixnum/fdiv.rb:1: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
! Unable to load application: Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor @ fptr_finalize_flush - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/1.9.1/io/open.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/1.9.1/io/open.rb:2:in `close': Bad file descriptor @ fptr_finalize_flush - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/1.9.1/io/open.rb (Errno::EBADF)
```

Here's what my code looks like:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/namespace'

namespace '/v1/picking' do
  post '/tasks/:task_id/barcodes/create' do
    barcode_content = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

    # DO SOME STUFF

    return 'OK'
  end
end
```

I'm using Ruby 2.4.1 and Sinatra 2.0.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like maybe a bug in `backports`. What happens if you update the [backports gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/backports) to the newest version?

Comment: What is your enviroment: OSX or Linux?

Comment: @IzumiSy it's OSX

Answer (score 0):

Backports 3.6.0 was broken due to some bugs. The offical says it is fixed. I checked 3.8.0 and it worked well. Upgrade your gems.

https://github.com/marcandre/backports/issues/91